# Discrete numerical optimization with black-box target function

Tags: numerical-methods, discrete-optimization

Let's say I have a function $f(x_1, \dots, x_n)$ of about 50 discrete variables mapping them to a natural number. Some are integers and so are orderable, but most are categorical features and don't have any good order on them (think eye color or a boolean variable). I don't know anything about the function either, besides its output on any given input (which is expensive to calculate, by the way — on the order of seconds). It also *seems* that *most* of the inputs are independent (in the sense that if $\hat{x}_j = \arg \min_{x_j} f(x_1, \dots, x_n)$ for a fixed $(x_1, \dots, x_{j - 1}, x_{j + 1} \dots, x_n)$, then $\hat{x}_j$ would be the argmin for any other choice of the other variables), but I know that there are some that are not, so I can use this independence for heuristics but cannot fully rely on it. I also don't know if the global minimum is at $0$ or if it's greater than $0$. Numerical optimization is one of my weakest math areas, so how do I minimize the output of this function?

One thing I know is a "reasonable" initial input vector (but it doesn't mean it's closest to the global optimum), so I'm not completely in the dark. Given that, I could only come up with the obvious algorithm of starting with that vector and then iteratively varying each of the variables, updating the vector at the single position giving the best decrease of the value of $f$, stopping as soon as I find myself in *some* minimum (which will happen since nats are well-founded). Almost-independence means such a greedy algorithm almost-makes-sense, but could I do better?

Comment: For black-box functions you can try Nelder-Mead (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nelder%E2%80%93Mead_method) or Powell method. They do not need any derivatives, only values of the function (zero-degree methods). I'm not sure about cathegorical features, but assume you can find some way to modify any of these.

Comment: Since the underlying model seems to be unknown  ("black box"), little can be said about making a search more informed.  You do seem to have in mind a function that returns non-negative integers, so perhaps you do have further knowledge.  It might lead to more advice if you describe the consequences for not finding the sought argmin.

Comment: @hardmath nothing too bad. What I'm trying to do is, given an existing code base (context: programming), derive a configuration for a source code formatter such that the formatter will change the code base in the least intrusive way (where intrusiveness is measured as a variation of the Levenshtein distance). I know edit distance is non-negative, but the formatter's workings are basically black box for me.